# Setting maven javadoc plugin to generate private methods/fields documentation

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I cannot find any example of maven pom where the javadoc plugin is used to generate documentation for private fields and methods too. I tried this without results:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <show>private</show>
                        <noHelp>true</noHelp>                           
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Anyone could help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the correct plugin. You are using maven-dependency-plugin while you should use maven-javadoc-plugin